# cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2() error on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, c, opencv, augmented-reality

I'm getting an error in OpenCV (v1.1,2.0,2.2) when using the cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2() method, it works with an iPhone3GS but falls over when tested on the iPhone4. The error is:

"incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed"

I ended up converting a whole lot of cvMat types to floats as opposed to doubles which resolved the issue but introduced the result overflowing giving me some strange results.

Does the iPhone4 have a stack limit for doubles?

Anyway - just wondering if anyone has resolved this issue? (also - anyone know of an optimized version?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you had the error, but to answer your question, the stack has a limited size.

On most systems, the size of `float` is **4** bytes and `double` is **8**. So when you use `double` to represent your data, you are actually using twice the space you would with `float`.

A simple workaround (if you can) is to **allocate memory for cvMat on the HEAP** instead of the stack. To do this, declare a pointer do `cvMat` and allocate space for it using the **new** operator.

The [Thread Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html) doc states that **stack size** of the **iOS main thread is 1 MB and 512K for secondary threads**. You might need to do the core of your processing on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the update - have gone through and refactored a whole lot of OpenCV code but still running into the same issue. Have further looked into it and think it may have something to do with how much memory is allocated for the operating thread. Need to double check this but think iOS v4.1 has a higher allocation than iOS v4.2+. If this is the case then think it should be an easy fix i.e. create a new thread to process it with a larger stack size.

Comment: Still having the same issue - am now looking at alternative implementations to determine pose because of these issues - one with less memory requirements as I've gone through the code and tried to move as much as I can to the heap with little success. Have also tried running the processing on different threads. Does anyone know if there is a tool that allows me to watch the stack usage for each thread?